# not able to store result in hdfs when code runs for second iteration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Well I am new to spark and scala and have been trying to implement cleaning of data in spark. below code checks for the missing value for one column and stores it in outputrdd and runs loops for calculating missing value. code works well when there is only one missing value in file. Since hdfs does not allow writing again on the same location it fails if there are more than one missing value. can you please assist in writing finalrdd to particular location once calculating missing values for all occurrences is done.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("app").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val files = sc.wholeTextFiles("/input/raw_files/")
val file = files.map { case (filename, content) => filename }

file.collect.foreach(filename => {
  cleaningData(filename)
})

def cleaningData(file: String) = {
  //headers has column headers of the files
  var hdr = headers.toString()
  var vl = hdr.split("\t")
  sqlContext.clearCache()
  if (hdr.contains("COLUMN_HEADER")) {
    //Checks for missing values in dataframe and stores missing values' in outputrdd
    if (!outputrdd.isEmpty()) {
      logger.info("value is zero then performing further operation")
      val outputdatetimedf = sqlContext.sql("select date,'/t',time from cpc where kwh = 0")
      val outputdatetimerdd = outputdatetimedf.rdd
      val strings = outputdatetimerdd.map(row => row.mkString).collect()
      for (i <- strings) {
        if (Coddition check) {
            //Calculates missing value and stores in finalrdd
              finalrdd.map { x => x.mkString("\t") }.saveAsTextFile("/output")
            logger.info("file is written in file")
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

}``

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how `(Coddition check)` works in your example.
In any case function `.saveAsTextFile("/output")` should be called only once.

So I would rewrite your example into this:

```
val strings = outputdatetimerdd
   .map(row => row.mkString)
   .collect() // perhaps '.collect()' is redundant

val finalrdd = strings
   .filter(str => Coddition check str) //don't know how this Coddition works
   .map (x => x.mkString("\t"))

// this part is called only once but not in a loop
finalrdd.saveAsTextFile("/output")
logger.info("file is written in file")
```

Comment: column1.equalsIgnoreCase("0.0") this is the condition and if condition is true it calculates missing value from history data and finalrdd is created from it having all the data + calculated missing value. This final rdd is needed to be written.